# p2p long term storage

Tags: storage, replication, p2p

We are building a long term preservation cluster made of 3 geographical (far) node of 32TB (each one).

The 3 nodes must have the same files (3 level redoundancy).

My idea is to use a p2p protocol to keep the 3 nodes syncronized. I mean: If someone puts a file (a document) on one node (using a specific web based app), the other 2 nodes must take a copy of it (in asyncronous way) automatically.

I searched for p2p file systems but it seems, in general, that they split files in many nodes and optimize access performances, which is not our case. We need only an automated replica system. We prevent large amount of files.

Anyone knows some open source project can help?

Thanks.

Comment: If you just need to replicate files, maybe you can write a simple script that use rsync. See the link below, http://tektext.blogspot.com/2010/01/filesystem-replication-using-rsync-and.html

Answer (score 0):

P2P is overkill in your case. Especially if your server have all a public address. `rsync` or something similar would be much easier to implement.

Comment: this fits more like a comment, the question remains unanswered.